# Display form on the bottom right of screen?

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, taskbar

I'm creating an application that is based on displaying some notifications which the user should Accept or Refuse

How can i show the request form on the right bottom of screen **not above taskbar** ?

[image]

Code :

```
notificationForm ntf = new notificationForm();
ntf.ShowDialog();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: notifications shouldn't appear above taskbar, think about the user please.

Comment: You could compute the window size, and grab the size of the (first) screen, then resize and set the location of the notification form appropriately. Do you need help with those things?

Comment: @CharlesB Sorry, corrected it. I mean not above taskbar, exactly like the image shows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
        int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width;
        int y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height;
        this.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really must have the notifications in a specific place then you need to use the

> [SystemParameters.WorkArea property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.workarea.aspx)

Which

> Gets the size of the work area on the primary display monitor.

for a WPF application.

or the

> [Screen.WorkingArea property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea.aspx)

which gets

> The working area is the desktop area of the display, excluding taskbars, docked windows, and docked tool bars.

for a WinForms application.

This can also be got like this:

```
Rectangle workingRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
```

From this information you'll be able to position your window where ever you like.